# I can´t Delete or Truncate Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Create a table from a storage account and I can insert records with no problem.
I decided to use this type of table to be able to share the URI (Https) and for another system to consume it, and since it is a NoSQL table, it gives me the possibility of adapting what I need to store in it.
But I have the inconvenience that this table, I must truncate it every time information is processed and the option from Data Factory where it indicates the insertion mode, (Replace or combine), does not work, it always performs an append.
I tried to do it from DataBricks, but I don't know how to reference that table, since it is outside of a Blob Storage and it cannot be mounted as such. any ideas?

Azure Table Storage
[image]

Azure data Factory
[image]

"Tipo de Inserción" = Insert Type
"Reemplazar" = Replace

Table Data
[image]

Configuration Data Factory
[image]

How to configure so that I can delete the data?

Thanks a lot.
Greetings.

Comment: How are you setting PartitionKey and RowKey in the data sending to Table?  Those are the unique keys of an Azure Table so must be set to an existing row in order for it to 'replace' it.

Comment: The PartitionKey and RowKey are added automatically when inserting the records

Comment: Then it will never replace a row, if you don't set those values then you will need to truncate prior to inserting.  The 'Replace' option will only replace rows that match on PartitionKey and  RowKey combination.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger, I edited my post to show how the configuration is and how the data is. Thank you very much.

Comment: *The PartitionKey and RowKey are added automatically when inserting the records* you need to read up on how table storage works. That's very wrong

Comment: Ok, would someone have an example of how to truncate a table before performing the insert? Thanks.